# p5.js weird texture behavior on 3D objects

Tags: javascript, 3d, textures, processing, p5.js

In a nutshell, what I'm trying to achieve is some basic texture mapping on a box() object. The texture itself is a square, b&w image.

I load the texture by loadImage(), call it through texture(), and map it on the cube. It seems to be working overall and the code runs without any issues but for some reason -I'm not completely sure how one would call it in this environment- I'm getting some kind of a back-face culling effect dynamically depending on the angle I'm looking at it from(see attached pic).

What might be the reason for that, and how could I get rid of this undesired effect?

ps:I'm using the built-in orbitControl() to navigate in the scene. Maybe that's what's causing the problem? Can't be sure, help appreciated.

[2d grid of 3d box() objects with some texture oddity on the top surface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggdC0.png)

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it as soon as I assigned a texture() to every different unit in the scene.
[fixed result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPdrz.png)